# Python Balloon Tips won't display in XP - wx GUI

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, winapi

I have a Python 2.7 Windows app with some Wx (3.0) gui features that is running perfectly in Windows 7....but I can't get the system tray icon balloon tips to work in Windows XP.  My company is still in the process of updating about 15,000 PC's and won't be finished until mid next year, so I want to get my software out for multiple versions until then.

I've searched for about a week now and can't seem to find an identical situation to my own, without completely dismantling my whole program and starting over (maybe thats what I need to do?)...  The other solutions involve recreating all windows from win32gui instead of the wx build that is at the foundation of the app. (I have a pop up menu, and multiple panels that open based on system tray menu selection).  I've double checked that all of my modules are 32 bit, but maybe I'm missing something else?

I've taken some elements from other examples I've found here to get it working in W7:

```
  def ShowBalloon(self, title, text, msec = 15, flags = 0):
    """
    Show Balloon tooltip
     @param title - Title for balloon tooltip
     @param msg   - Balloon tooltip text
     @param msec  - Timeout for balloon tooltip, in milliseconds
     @param flags -  one of wx.ICON_INFORMATION, wx.ICON_WARNING, wx.ICON_ERROR
    """
    self.icon = wx.Icon(os.getcwd() + "\Icons\Main.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
    if WIN32 and self.IsIconInstalled():
        try:
            self.__SetBalloonTip(self.icon.GetHandle(), title, text, msec, flags)
        except Exception as e:
          pass # print(e) Silent error

def __SetBalloonTip(self, hicon, title, msg, msec, flags):

    # translate flags
    print flags
    infoFlags = 0
    self.icon = wx.Icon(os.getcwd() + "\Icons\Main.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)

    if flags & wx.ICON_INFORMATION:
        infoFlags |= win32gui.NIIF_INFO
    elif flags & wx.ICON_WARNING:
        infoFlags |= win32gui.NIIF_WARNING
    elif flags & wx.ICON_ERROR:
        infoFlags |= win32gui.NIIF_ERROR



    # Show balloon
    lpdata = (self.__GetIconHandle(),   # hWnd
              99,                       # ID
              win32gui.NIF_MESSAGE|win32gui.NIF_INFO|win32gui.NIF_ICON, # flags: Combination of NIF_* flags
              0,                        # CallbackMessage: Message id to be pass to hWnd when processing messages
              hicon,                    # hIcon: Handle to the icon to be displayed
              '',                       # Tip: Tooltip text
              msg,                      # Info: Balloon tooltip text
              msec,                     # Timeout: Timeout for balloon tooltip, in milliseconds
              title,                    # InfoTitle: Title for balloon tooltip
              infoFlags                 # InfoFlags: Combination of NIIF_* flags
              )
    win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_MODIFY, lpdata)

    self.SetIcon(self.icon, self.tooltip)   # Hack: because we have no access to the real CallbackMessage value

def __GetIconHandle(self):
        """
        Find the icon window.
        This is ugly but for now there is no way to find this window directly from wx
        """
        if not hasattr(self, "_chwnd"):
            try:
                for handle in wx.GetTopLevelWindows():
                    if handle.GetWindowStyle():
                        continue
                    handle = handle.GetHandle()
                    if len(win32gui.GetWindowText(handle)) == 0:
                        self._chwnd = handle
                        break
                if not hasattr(self, "_chwnd"):
                    raise Exception
            except:
                raise Exception, "Icon window not found"
        return self._chwnd
```

I don't get any errors or exceptions in XP, but the balloon tips just won't display.  The tips are called based on receipt of incoming TCP messages, and display details of the incoming message.  I am very much a novice, thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the problem may be the timeout value, whose behaviour was different prior to Vista. Checkout the Remarks section of MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the `BalloonTip` widget that is builtin to wxPython. It is in `wx.lib.agw.balloontip`. It doesn't look quite native since it is a custom widget, but it should work across multiple versions of Windows just fine.

You can see an example in the wxPython demo package. There is also a short example here:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.balloontip.html